# Fix spelling errors in epub file via rtf of same book?

Tags: epub, calibre, editing

I am reading a book I got as ePub but it has a lot of OCR errors, for example: "is" becomes "!5" and so on. I tried to find another version of the book without the errors but the only one I could find is an RTF file, meaning it doesn't have the formatting I like from the ePub.

I am therefore wondering if it's possible to fix the errors in the ePub by comparing the text in the ePub and the RTF and then replacing the errors in the ePub with the correct words from the RTF.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify epub files with an epub editor.

Two free options are [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/) and [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good RTF, you're probably better off just converting it directly to ePub with calibre, and not bothering with editing it at all.